# Weird mouse tracking issue

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

I just got a Logitech G203. When I use it on the table, lift up it and try to use it on mousepad it doesn't work. But when I slide it over from table to mousepad it works fine. It's really weird. What might be causing it?

Edit: It's a wooden hard table, and mousepad is a regular cloth mousepad.
Also any other surface works after using it on the table too. Just the mousepad I have to slide it over from table to mousepad for it to work.

Comment: What type of surface?  Edit your question.  Please do not submit a comment.

Comment: Did you try a different mouse pad?  Hard finished wooden surfaces can affect the reflection of the mouse signal.  Experience has taught me that one. If various surfaces cause an issue, contact LogiTech Support.

Comment: @john I don't have any other mouse pad but other surfaces work fine, but I can't think of a reason why it would do this on mousepad. It works on mousepad, but not after using it on the table.

Comment: I think it possible (never seen it myself) for the reflective properties of the mouse to carry over a bit. That is why I suggest contacting LogiTech Support